# android: google map v2 not working when I run from my computer

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

Google maps v2 is implemented in my app.  It works fine when it is run with other computer.

But it is not showing `Map` when `Apk` is generated with my computer.

Is there any settings to change in my PC?. Please suggest me.

Google maps API key is generated with Signed key.

Comment: you have changed the key into your manifest.xml file after new release

Comment: in both systems, api key is same

Comment: that's why you can't see the map.

Comment: Why? API Key is generated with signed keystore file. API key is unique right ? It should show map.

Comment: but in the different systems you need to generate a new keystore and also make change into your project manifest.xml and then sign your apk again with your new created keystore.

Comment: I think we need same .keystore file to release apk in PlayStore, rihgt ?. So how can we create new .keystore file and release into PlayStore

Comment: Create new key from developer console using your system sh1 and then run.

Answer (score 11):

You are absolutely right you do not need to change the api key it is unique.

So you don't need to change anything in manifest.xml.

But, As you said when you run the project from your computer it does not showing the map. Because when you run the project by default it sign the apk with debug.keystore.

So now what you have to do is, just generate the SHA-1 from your pc using debug.keystore and make entry of that SHA-1 in google api console.

You can add multiple SHA-1 in your project settings at google api console.

Just see the screenshot you will got the idea.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you run form your computer then debug.keystore used and when you create apk then keystore is change and also SH1 key is changed so your map is not show when you create apk.

Solution: create new api key for apk, use this key when you create apk. [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) link help you to get SH1 key from keystore

Comment: Remember different PC have different sh1 key. So it  necessary to create new api key to show map

Comment: you are right that different computers have different SHA-1 keys. But You did't need to generate new API key for each one. It was it MAP API -1. In MAP API-2 you can edit your project and set multiple SHA-1 for same key.

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia ya, i read your ans, its very helpful for us. i up mark on your answer